# compare current date with expires date stored in mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, date, datetime

I am building an application using react native and NodeJS as backend server that communicate with MySQL database.
I During a process in the app, I insert an expires date in column, this value is coming from the following function in backend server:

```
function getDate() {
  var d = new Date();
  var date = d.getDate();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var hour = d.getHours() + 2;
  var min = d.getMinutes();
  var sec = d.getSeconds();
  return (year + "-" + month + "-" + date + " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
}
```

is this function gives me the date which during inserting will be two hours a head of inserting time.

on other hand, another inserting process is happening , while inserting it takes the current date which handled by `NOW()` within inserting query.

so let's say date now is: 2021-01-22 13:00:00

the above function will give this date: `2021-01-22 15:00:00`

and `NOW()` will give this date: `2021-01-22 13:00:00`

so I want to set condition to compare these two dates, `2021-01-22 15:00:00` and `2021-01-22 13:00:00`

I have tried this condition:

```
 else if (row.length > 0 && row[0].att_expires.getTime() < cuurentdate.getTime())
```

but this is gave me error `ReferenceError: getTime is not defined`

I tried also :

```
`else if (row.length > 0 && row[0].att_expires < cuurentdate)`
```

but it always gives false value for this condition which means is not comparing these two values!!

I hope someone can help me how to get rid of this problem.

Comment: The value returned from SQL will not be a javascript date, try converting it first: let expires = new Date(row[0].att_expires)) and then compare expires to currentdate

Comment: @HeraldSmit thank you so much, you really saved my day. it works!!!